# How change exit code for ansible-playbook if exist change in running?

Tags: ansible

I run playbook in check mode in Gitlab CI and I want that CI failed if exist changed in running.

Maybe exist other solution for my issue?

Now used bash script which parsing strings and if exist "changed" return exit code 1

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

you can use "register" along with "failed_when" parameter in your playbook.
[error_handling](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html)

I will able to give your piece of code if you can elaborate your question with what is excepted and your playbook snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it isn't possible by using Ansible.

The only solution we have is to parse the output of the playbook